# Angular.copy - require more clarification

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I seen a sample work as like the folloing.. after I see this example i had couple of questions to understand the `angular.copy` any one help me to understand?

here is the full of code with html and js:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="parking">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Car Parking</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module("parking", []);
        myApp.controller('parkingCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

            $scope.cars = [
                {plate: '6MBV006'},
                {plate: '5BBM299'},
                {plate: '5AOJ230'}
            ]

            $scope.park = function (car) {
                $scope.cars.push(angular.copy(car));
                console.log(angular.copy(car));
                delete $scope.car;
            }

        }]);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="parkingCtrl">
    <h3>[Packt] Parking</h3>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Plate</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td ng-repeat="car in cars">{{car.plate}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <label for="plate">
        <input type="text" ng-model="car.plate">
    </label>    
    <button ng-click="park(car)">Park</button>
</body>
```

1. After I clicking I am passing a car from button, how the `car.plate` retrived from input box to `park(car)` function?
2. We can simply push the object to array, then what is the reason to use the `$scope.cars.push(angular.copy(car));` what it does for us exactly?
3. why should we delete the object `delete $scope.car;`?

Any one please help me to understand this logic behind the angular please?

[Here is the working example](http://jsfiddle.net/s2jtq03r/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Angular is automatically creating a property for you on the scope called `car` and populating the `plate` property of `car` with the text input.

The code is then creating a 'deep copy' of that object to push in to the array. `angular.copy` creates a 'deep copy' of the object instead of just pushing the reference to that object in to the array. Read more: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Deleting the $scope.car object is just a quick way of removing that property from the $scope so angular will recreate it if the user types in a new plate number

Comment: If you delete the `car` property anyway, then there's no need to create a copy. So your answer doesn't fully cover question 2: What is the reason?

Comment: He needs to create a copy to store in the $scope.cars array.

Answer (score 1):

Well you really don't *need* to use `angular.copy` in the example you've shown.

1. Because when you declare `car.plate` as the `ng-model` of the text box, a car object is automatically created for you on the scope.
2. Who said you need to use angular.copy here? Imagine you had an edit button next to each of those cars, and you wants to break the 2
   way
   binding between the car displayed in the tale and the one being
   edited, for example until when the user clicks a confirm edit button,
   then you use angular.copy to make a copy of the object being displayed
   in the ng-repeat such that it doesn't change while the user is typing
   something. angular.copy is used to break the reference to an object. 
   If removing those results in a `[ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a
   repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique
   keys.` error, then that could be solved by a track by. Effectively
   using `angular.copy` creates a new car object every time it's passed
   into the array.
3. To create add a new car object every time to the list, you can either delete the scope property so that it's re instantiated as a new object, or pass a copy of $scope.car to the list so that it treats each item as a different entity.

Comment: It is not inside the ng-repeat ...The car in the ng-repeat is local to the scope of the ng-repeat only

Comment: @link64 my bad, didn't look at the fiddle properly, corrected my answer.